# Mathematica : Add text to imported image / graphic as a label

Tags: image, text, wolfram-mathematica, label, graphic

Ive searched for hours ... but Im at a loss !

I have imported an image int Mathematica -> dimensions 2x2cm at 72DPI.

I am trying to "label" the image with a text string that:
- has font color "fontColor"
- has a black outline, so it contrasts to any underlying color
- sits in the bottom right corner of the imported image
- has size h/w in cm
- optionally sits in a text box with a white background

This is how far ive come:

MathCode:

```
image = Import["myimg.jpg"];
inchFactor = 2.54;(* 1 inch = 2.54cm *)
docRes = 72;
pixelConverter = docRes/inchFactor/2;

myText = First[
   First[ImportString[
     ExportString[
      Style["glorious label string here", Bold, FontSize -> 15, 
       FontFamily -> "Verdana"], "PDF"], "PDF", 
     "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];

myTextGraphic = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]]], White, 
    myText}, Background -> White, 
   ImageSize -> {10*pixelConverter, 2*pixelConverter}];
myTextGraphic = Rasterize[myTextGraphic];

combined = SetAlphaChannel[myTextGraphic, myTextGraphicAlphaVersion];
```

I found the above method (PDF wrapper) for the black outline of the text string.

I am adding an AlphaChannel to the graphic of the text string using a version of it that only uses black/white.

I then try to combine the images with Overlay.

As none of this seems to work concerning the outputted image size and positioning, Im kindly asking for help.
There´s no need to "fix" that messy code.

Maybe you could point me to a script or tutorial - all I really want is to add and position a text string or text box to an underlying image.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Would you like me to move this question over to our Mathematica specialist site. You might get better help there. @ ping me or flag for a moderator to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this. There are other ways too.

```
img = Import["http://todayinsci.com/H/Hilbert_David/HilbertDavidThm.jpg"];

Column[{
  img,
  Text[Style["Professor Hilbert", Red]]
}]

imgCtr = Round[ImageDimensions[img]/2];

overlay = Framed[Graphics[{Text[Style["Professor Hilbert", Red, 9], imgCtr]},ImageSize-> {66, 14}], FrameStyle -> Green]

Overlay[{img, overlay}, Alignment -> Center]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's late here so this is only the beginning of a solution for you but here's a simple way to add a text label to an image:

```
lbl = Graphics[Text[Style["Bottom", Red, Large]]]
```

which creates an image with the text 'Bottom' in red in a large font.  Next, given an image called `img1`

```
ImageCompose[img1,lbl]
```

puts the text in the centre of the image.  `ImageCompose` has options to allow you to position the second image (ie the label) wrt the first image.  You can put the label on a coloured background like this:

```
lbl = Graphics[Text[Style["Bottom", Red, Large, Background -> Blue]]]
```

I haven't figured out, yet, how to write the text with a coloured outline.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! Your answer also told me that Ill have to have a closer look at the function hierarchy ;) Thx!